# Rescaling a image with Android tutorial method

Tags: android, android-intent, thumbnails, android-camera

I am using this tutorial as a guideline for adding a functionality to my app:

**http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html**

The example coming with the tutorial is incomplete containing some "mistakes". I put the word mistakes in quotes because the main tutorial's purpouse is covered: work with the camera.

I am focusing on obtain a thumbnail photo from the big one taken. When you run the example you rapidly notice that most of the time the thumbnail for the big photo is not displayed although it is correctly stored in the denoted dir.

Doing a bit of work I discovered the following "mistakes":

1.- The image's path value is frequently lost because the activity is destroyed due to a lack of memory. I fixed that storing the path to the photo in the method onSaveInstanceState().

This way I was always able to access my image but it still did not appear. I continued making some tests and discovered:

2.- Most of the times, when asking for the imageview's measures (width and high) for rescaling the image the values were 0. I thought this could be the problem and found it was caused because you cannot obtain the measures until the view was drawn. So I fixed that with a handler and sending a delayed message (1.5'') to be executed. Now, the measures are always obtained correctly but even though the thumbnail is not displayed most of the times

So I thought the Bitmap.decodeFile method was returning a null value dispite all the variables were setting correctly. But it is not, it is returning a bitmap. So guys and girls, I recognize I am not able to find why the thumbnail is not displayed.

A bit of help would be very appreciated. Thanks!

This is the method for rescaling the image:

```
//Scaling the real size photo to the image view size
private void setImagenPequena()
{
    Log.w("PAth: ", n_path_foto_actual);
     // Get the dimensions of the View
    int targetW = n_iv_foto.getMeasuredWidth();
    int targetH = n_iv_foto.getMeasuredHeight();

    // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(n_path_foto_actual, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    Log.w("setImagenPequena: ", "photoW: " + Integer.toString(photoW));
    Log.w("setImagenPequena: ", "photoH: " + Integer.toString(photoH));
    Log.w("setImagenPequena: ", "targetW: " + Integer.toString(targetW));
    Log.w("setImagenPequena: ", "targetH: " + Integer.toString(targetW));

    if(targetW > 0 && targetH > 0)
    {
    // Determine how much to scale down the image
    int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    }
    // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(n_path_foto_actual, bmOptions);

    if(bitmap == null)
        Log.w("valor bitmap: ", "null");
    else
        Log.w("valor bitmap: ", "!=null");
    n_iv_foto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got many issues as well with this tutorial, but I finally fixed it.
what I did :

- Change

> int scaleFactor = Math.**min**(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

by

> int scaleFactor = Math.**max**(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

was the key thing. Before that i got blank image instead of the picture.

- I put a default picture in my view. It may not be an all-around answer but I thought it gives a better user experience anyway.
- You can use http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=590 to get a working decodeSampledBitmapFromFile example.
- Otherwise use some of my code here :

  ```
  WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
  Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
  Point size = new Point();
  display.getSize(size);
  mWidth = size.x;
  mHeight = size.y;
  ...

  private void setPic() {

          int targetW = mWidth;
          int targetH = mHeight;
          // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
          BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
          bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

          BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
          int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
          int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

          // Determine how much to scale down the image
          int scaleFactor = Math.max(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);
          bmOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
          // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
          bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
          bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
          bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

          Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath,                 
          bmOptions);
          mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
  }
  ```